# Twitter like News Feed with Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database

One of the things I can not wrap my head around is how a news feed type system would work.

I understand basic querys and all of that jazz, what I don't understand.. from an efficiency stand is how OLD Tweets I have already loaded would be updated.

For example, my app initially loads, and my query returns these results:

***Initial Load***

- Tweet 1

  - Favorite Count: 5
  - Message: "Blah Blah Blah"
  - Creator: "Bob" etc...
- Tweet 2

  - Favorite Count: 2
  - Message: "random message"
  - Creator: "Bart" etc...

So lets say above is my example load.. I pulled down two tweets. Say then later on my user uses the pull to refresh function to trigger another load.. its been a few hours and another user has tweeted something out.

For an efficiency standpoint, and to limit the time and data that needs to be streamed.. it would be sense to remeber where we left off at Tweet 2, and to only load items that have been added.

However... The Favorite Count and other elements of our already loaded tweets could now be different. You are likely not the only other user utilizing the app. How would you efficiently query for that? Would you requery on every tweet.. would you pull down complete tweets everytime?

The Second load could truly look something like this:

***Pull To Refresh Manual Load***

- Tweet 1

  - Favorite Count: 300
  - Message: "Blah Blah Blah"
  - Creator: "Bob" etc...
- Tweet 2

  - Favorite Count: 222
  - Message: "random message"
  - Creator: "Bart" etc...
- Tweet 3

  - Favorite Count: 1
  - Message: "Newest Tweet"
  - Creator: "Jim"

As you can see above the newest Tweet.. Tweet 3 was added by a user and would be loaded in the next load. The Favorite Count could be different on Tweet 1 and 2 and it would be important to update those in the Interface, but seems redundant every pull to refresh to pull down a ton of JSON each time.

Or is this database structure just wrong...

any help would be huge.. been trying to figure out how to do this for a while

Comment: "Say then later on my user uses the pull to refresh function to trigger another load" With Firebase it's more idiomatic to actually keep an active listener. So instead of using "pull to refresh",  the data is pushed to the client instantly and the screen can be "always up to date".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah.. I love the listener portions of firebase.. I use that elsewhere..

Comment: However.. what I am trying to figure out is if I were using a Pull To Refresh Model.. how would you go about updating elements further down? Does an app like twitter just completely requery all tweets.. I doubt that..

Comment: There are a lot of options on how to minimize data transfer. Speculating on what Twitter does seems inefficient though. In some cases the Firebase clients do a delta-sync, in which case they send a composite hash code of the branches it has cached to the server. But such hashes are quite complex to calculate and may outweigh the actual data size in a simple data model such as yours. an alternative approach is to store the actual deltas instead of just the values (in database parlance that would be a log or "op log"). That way the client can query for just the changes since they last "pulled".